# Can't delete file (you need permission/file open in another program)

Tags: windows-7

So I was going through an old HDD that was once the primary HDD for my old laptop, browsing through it in my new desktop.

I decided to delete the entire contents but it's stuck on two files

`F:\old\bin\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\Flash32_1\1_6_602_171.ocx`
`F:\old\bin\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash64_11_6_602_171.ocx`

However I get a "you don't have permissions" error.
I have tried the "take ownership" command, which worked for all the other files.

That's what happens if I `delete` it, but if I `shift + delete` I get "the file is open in another program".

I guarantee you, this file is *not* open in another program.

Comment: a quick solution would be to boot from a Linux live disc and delete the files

Comment: Download and open Process Explorer, and then do a handle search (Ctrl+F) for "F:\old\bin\Windows". It should list which processes are busy using those files (perhaps a virus scanner?).

Comment: Yeah not bad idea. I have a Debian CD at work I could use.
0 matches found for Process Explorer.
I can rename the files. But if you mean reformat the drive.. well I still use the drive. I guess 'entire contents' wasn't quite the correct description.

Comment: Did you double click them or keep open a properties window specific to those files?  If they were initialized (for any reason), you wouldn't be able to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tool [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to unlock the file or kill the process, which uses the file. So you don't need to start with a Live-CD to delete the file.

After you downloaded the unlocker, there is an additional option in the contextmenu called *Unlocker*.

[image]

Just click on it, and it will delete all the files.